# Date have to changed according to location in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Can somebody help me with this.
If im using the Application Developed with ADF, It should change the Date and time According to the location where Im using it. For Exmaple, If im using in US/UK, Date and Time should change accordingly..

Can you guys suggest me something with this.?

Answer (score 0):

What you get **Out Of The Box** in ADF though Internationalisation 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/web.1111/b31973/af_global.htm#ADFUI425
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8fS7axk6Ho

is the ability to get Date, Time and Number formatting according to user browser's locale. This is a bit different from what you are asking, but I would dare saying - better. Myself, I have had so many bad experiences while being in Sweden or Denmark and getting some of the websites I regularly use translated to Swedish automatically.

But if your use case strongly requires this feature, you will need to retrieve the client browser's IP and from the IP you can get the Country.
Something like here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/23102/getting-country-based-on-ip

Comment: This is kind of static Way of changing the language. But i want something like dynamic. If im fetching something from DB, if i choose different languagse, it should change that too...

Comment: This is what you get "out of the box" - browser is going to select the language automatically, based on user's locale. If you need to customise the language selection programatically, you can do it by calling FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().setLocale(newLocale) from an action listener.
More details here:
http://biemond.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/change-language-locale-in-adf.html

Comment: In this We've given the LOV explicitly for English n Dutch. But the one im asking is like, In the home page, if i choose different language, it should change Dynamically, with-out mentioning explicitly. Is there a way to do it.?